# Save in a variable and multiply double value query result C#/MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, executenonquery, executequery

I'm trying to save the unique value resulting from a query into a double variable, since the same is stored in the database as double, so I can later be able to multiply it with a counter, with the following code:

```
 public partial class CoronaClaraCant : Form
 {
    private int conteoCliks = 0;
    private string producto = "CoronaClara";
    private double precio;

    public CoronaClaraCant()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void CoronaClara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=database;username=root;password=***"); 
        conn.Open();

        string select = "SELECT precio FROM productos where prodnom = '" + producto + "';";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(select, conn);
        double result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conteoCliks++;
        precio = result;


        double total = (precio * conteoCliks);


        lblcantidad.Text = conteoCliks.ToString();
        lblprecio.Text = precio.ToString();

        lbltotal.Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

**So far I've only been getting negative values:**

[image: Execution of the code]

I'm guessing this could be because the **ExecuteNonQuery**, but I haven't been able to assign a double value to a ExecuteScalar method, and I'm not sure if there are other parameters I should consider when saving a double value into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `select` data from database and you are calling `ExecuteNonQuery` which is used for **Insert,Update or Delete commands**.

You need to call `ExecuteReader` or if you want to get data in a `DataTable` you can fill a `DataTable`.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
   if (rdr.Read()) 
    {
      precio = (double)rdr["precio"];
    }
}
```